# "Shout in a whisper" verb

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What is the verb that means something close to shout and call out to sb but quieter? I mean when you shout something to a person that is far away but you don't want anyone else to hear so you hush your voice (but still you shout). I've searched for "shouted in a whisper" but it somehow sounds strange to me.

Comment: Are you thinking of a [*stage whisper*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/stage%20whisper): n. a loud whisper that can be overheard; on the stage it is heard by the audience but it supposed to be inaudible to the rest of the cast

Comment: I believe the words you are looking for are Stage Whisper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a verb and it is - ta-da! - ***whisper-shout***.

> The act of screaming at someone without using any vowel sounds, so as to keep the volume of the scream down to a nominal level. Similar to the well known "SHHHH!" but it is actually a word or a group of words.
>
> Often used in classroom or library settings, it can also be useful in churches or as a warning that someone unwelcome is approaching. [[Urbandictionary]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Whisper-shout)

It is not in canonical dictionaries but it is a clever coinage. You can find many examples in [Google Books](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22it%20has%20quite%20a%20usage%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=0-BEVeJsxK_IBLfTgKAH#q=%22whisper-shouted%22&tbm=bks&start=0) also.

Some examples:

> "Shh!" Veronica looked into the kitchen and adjoining dining room. "Empty," she whispered. "They must be upstairs. Let's get going."
>
> "No!" I **whisper-shouted**. "We've come this far. We've got to get some pictures!"
>
> <sub>*Limoncello Yellow: Franki Amato Mysteries book #1* By Traci Andrighetti</sub>
>
> ---
>
> “Cover me,” she **whisper-shouted**. “Where are you going?” Alicia **whisper-shouted back**.
>
> <sub>*The Clique #7: It's Not Easy Being Mean* By Lisi Harrison</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard nor read the term **whisper-shout** before today. I checked in Urban Dictionary, there is one definition and that has *only* eighteen upvotes against four downvotes. This tells me that the expression is not yet established. Chances are it won't be too soon either.

The compound “whisper-shouted” on Google Books obtains 839 results
While its equivalent expression, “[whispered loudly](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22it%20has%20quite%20a%20usage%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=0-BEVeJsxK_IBLfTgKAH#tbm=bks&q=%22whispered%20loudly%22)”, obtains 24,600 results

The single-word *‘hiss’* on the other hand is well known, and is listed in all good dictionaries.

> [**hiss**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/hiss): to say something **in a quiet angry** way
>   *"Shut up, Tom!" she hissed.*

Answer (score 1):

To shout in a  [subdued](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subdued) voice:

> - reduced in fullness of tone, as a color or sound; muted. (AHD)

Comment: I'd prefer _muted_ itself: 'another answered with a muted shout' / 'There was a muted shout for a penalty' / 'Jurado sustains his vocal cords in a muted shout' / 'another answered with a muted shout' (all from the internet). 'Subdued' at least connotes low mood.

Answer (score 0):

The two, “shout” and “whisper,” are pretty much opposites, so finding a single word is going to be tough (too tough for me, at least) and even attempts to modify “shout” (or “whisper”) with a single-word adverb/modifier could produce borderline oxymora.  However, if you’re willing to consider a phrase, I’d propose

> ... shouted as [discreetly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discreet) as possible.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like saying someone hushedly shouted would be an appropriate term for what you are trying to express.